# Index-Match Two Columns & Two Search types

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to do a two column match where one looks for values greater than the lookup value and one looks for an exact match?

Ex. I have a list of people and check in dates. I want to look up and exact person for the first date greater than my query date.

```
 Row 1: John Doe |  1/2/17
 Row 2: John Doe |  3/16/17
```

Looking up "John Doe" and "2/19/17" would result in row 2

**This is different from the other two column look up questions that I have seen because the match type is different for the two columns. One is exact, one is less than (0 & -1 in the match formula).

Comment: This is different from the other two column look up questions that I have seen because the match type is different for the two columns. One is exact, one is less than (0 & -1 in the match formula).

Comment: no, it is not, you would simple use "<=" in the Aggregate one that is provided in the answer.

Comment: You can also use the `"<="` with the SUMIFS version if the output is a number.

Comment: just a hint: `AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A1:A2)/((A1:A2="John Doe")*(B1:B2>="2/19/17"),1)` is the aggregate part.